# Using range-variable in multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue while using a **variable containing a range**.

I've declared the variable "rng" globally in the workbook module:

```
Public rng As Range
```

Now in a worksheet module I set the variable after clicking on a checkbox and define a range for it:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Set rng = Range("D8:Q51")

    If Me.OLEObjects("checkbox1").Object.Value Then
        Call clear(rng)
    Else
        Call aus(rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

I always get an error when calling the sub "aus(rng)" which says:

> error 438, object doesn't support this property or method

"aus(rng)" contains the following code:

```
Worksheets(5).rng.Copy Worksheets("aktuell").rng
```

Btw: using the range-variable in the same worksheet the module is connected to doesn't throw out an error. So the error somehow has to correlate with "Worksheets(5)".

Comment: Define `rng` in a normal module, not a workbook or worksheet module.

Comment: @Gareth When `rng` is defined, isn't it grabbing the default book and sheet?  So basically it is like writing `Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D8:Q51")`...

Comment: @Chrismas007 - Even if there was no confusion in the wb/ws parent of `rng`, the `Call aus(rng)` attempts to redefine it as belonging to `Worksheets(5)`. It seems to be used closer to a `rng.Address` than a `rng`. There is also no need to even pass it across as a parameter if it is declared globally.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Doh, and yes you're right.

Comment: Note `rng` already contains which `Worksheet` it belongs to. `Sheets(5).rng` is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a Range with `Set` and you don't define the parent objects of Workbook or Worksheet, it will default to `ActiveWorkBook` and `ActiveWorkSheet`.  Therefore it is like writing:

```
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D8:Q51")
```

When you use the `rng` later in the code, you try and assign it under a `Sheet` which is basically writing:

```
Worksheets(5).ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D8:Q51").Copy
```

Which we know is incorrect syntax and will error.

**As a workaround, you could use the following code:**

```
Worksheets(5).Range(rng.Address).Copy Worksheets("aktuell").Range(rng.Address)
```